# Toggle effect inverted after updating DOM element

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-hover, jquery

I have a table with some checkboxes. When the user clicks on any checkbox, the content of the cell is updated.

The table has a toggle effect over each group of rows. This effects gets inverted when I update the cell with the checkbox with jQuery.

Here's a simple fiddle with the problem. Notice how the toggle effect gets inverted after clicking in the checkbox and therefor the rows are highlighted when the mouse is OUT, which is not what I'm looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/s4tWd/

This is the jQuery used: ( I couldn't make .on('hover'..  work on jsfiddle )

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr[data-demo]').hover(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.siblings('[data-demo="'+t.attr('data-demo')+'"]').toggleClass('hover');
        t.toggleClass('hover');
    });

    $('.demo').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().html('text');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the call back function to remove class which is set on hover. See [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/s4tWd/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('tr[data-demo]').hover(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.siblings('[data-demo="'+t.attr('data-demo')+'"]').addClass('hover');
    t.addClass('hover');
  },function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.siblings('[data-demo="'+t.attr('data-demo')+'"]').removeClass('hover');
    t.removeClass('hover');
  });

  $('.demo').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().html('text');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your hover to mouseover and mouseout. It works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr[data-demo]').mouseover(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.siblings('[data-demo="'+t.attr('data-demo')+'"]').addClass('hover');
        t.addClass('hover');
    });
    $('tr[data-demo]').mouseout(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.siblings('[data-demo="'+t.attr('data-demo')+'"]').removeClass('hover');
        t.removeClass('hover');
    });

    $('.demo').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().html('text');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VinnyFonseca/s4tWd/1/